# Showing Sass::SyntaxError when using bootstrap 3.3.0 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using bootstrap 3.3.0 in my rails app but is showing below error

**Error compiling asset application.css: Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'hide-text'.
(in ../app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
Served asset /application.css - 500 Internal Server Error**

Here is my application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";  
@import "bootstrap-timepicker";  
@import "bootstrap-datepicker";

@import "globals/functions";  
@import "globals/mixins";  
@import "globals/variables";

/*@import "base";  
@import "layout";*/  
@import "style";  
@import "vistyle";  
@import "framework_and_overrides"; 

@import "modules/events";  
@import "modules/gallery";  
@import "modules/forms";
```

**Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'hide-text'.**

hide-text is written in modules/events.css.scss file.

Its working fine with bootstrap '2.3.1.0' but not for bootstrap '3.3.0' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have something to do with the version of Rails you are using. You have not specified it, but I'll assume it is Rails 3.2 (as I've had the same issue with it.) I also assume that you have the gem in the 'assets' group. If that's the case your app looks very similar to the one I've had the same issue with.

Basically this is because by default in Rails 3.2, assets group gems are not required in `production`.

For details, see the updated docs in the bootstrap-sass README:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/commit/1a4ff080af2be55f1c17b5d2c99eb5f31aaf2e97